# error: '_Out_' has not been declared when including <Kinect.h>

Tags: c++, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm using CLion and I need to get some data from the Kinect, but when it comes to `#include <Kinect.h>` I get the following error:

```
    In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~2/Kinect/V2D305~1.0_1/inc/Kinect.h:547,
             from C:\Users\fredd\CLionProjects\3D_avatar\main.cpp:19:
    C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~2/Kinect/V2D305~1.0_1/inc/Kinect.INPC.h:109:13: error: '_Out_' has not been declared
         _Out_  WAITABLE_HANDLE *waitableHandle) = 0;
         ^~~~~
```

And an endless list of similar errors. I think I miss some kind of library that defines this data format, but I really don't know (if that's the problem) which one. I've searched all over the internet and googled for about 3 hours without any result.
How can I solve the error?
Also, is there a better way to make Kinect works with CLion?

Comment: Which compiler is CLion configured to use? `_Out_` seems to be a [Microsoft-specific annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/understanding-sal?view=vs-2019), and may not compile using other compilers.

Comment: I'm using MinGW, and I need it because of OpenGL. Is there any way to compile OpenGL with that compiler using CLion?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can compile OpenGL with VC++. Search for how to install MSVC compiler and configure CLion to use it.

Comment: Ok so I managed to do that but now I have a weird error: the program says that some glm methods are overloaded and my definition in the program is ambiguous. The silly thing is that this doesn't happen when compiling with MinGW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to understand what was going on: MinGW couldn't compile [SAL annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/understanding-sal?view=vs-2019), so I had to switch compiler to MSVC, bundled with Visual Studio. Also, I had to link MatLab with my project since there's no library (except for `libfreenect2`, which has driven me mad) that can handle a Kinect v2.